# Chapter Title and Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

If I use code such as:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\subfile{intro/Introduction}

\chapter{Remaining Work}
\subfile{remaining/Remaining}
```

The result is:

```
Chapter 1
Introduction

Chapter 2 
Remaining Work
```

I'd like to remove the "Chapter 1" etc title, preferably replacing with the number and title.

If I use:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
```

Then the Chapter 1 label is removed, however, this ruins the table of contents - sections are labelled 0.1, 0.2 etc without ever being labelled by chapter.

How can I remove the Chapter N label and keep the numbering on the table of contents correct?

EDIT:

Full working example (changing chapter to chapter*):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
Test
\section{Test1}
Test
\subsection{Test1.1}
Test
\section{Test2}
Test
\section{Test3}
Test
\section{Test4}
Test

\chapter{Remaining Work}
Test
\section{Test1}
Test
\subsection{Test1.1}
Test
\section{Test2}
Test
\section{Test3}
Test
\section{Test4}
Test

\clearpage
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your question depends heavily on the documentclass being used. Do you want to have just the chapter title, no `Chapter N` leadin ?

Comment: Take a look at the `titlesec` package and its companion `titletoc`, at least if you use one of the standard classes.

Comment: Have added an example

Answer (score 2):

In the standard `book` class, the macro `\@makechapterhead` creates the chapter title leadin, starting with `Chapter N.... chapter title`.

Using the `xpatch` package, this leadin can be removed and stripped down to the pure title only with `xpatchcmd`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{xpatch}%

\makeatletter  % For \mainmatter chapters so far only!
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}{\huge\bfseries}{}{}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
Test
\section{Test1}
Test
\subsection{Test1.1}
Test
\section{Test2}
Test
\section{Test3}
Test
\section{Test4}
Test

\chapter{Remaining Work}
Test
\section{Test1}
Test
\subsection{Test1.1}
Test
\section{Test2}
Test
\section{Test3}
Test
\section{Test4}
Test

\clearpage
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

[image]